# Dropdown in Flex Navbar pushes content

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to add a dropdown to a Navbar, however, when hovering on the dropdown button (Kieli, in my case), center alignment pushes the rest of the items out of the way. I have attached a snippet with an example of my problem.

```css
.Navbar {
    display: flex;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: lightgray;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.Navbar-menu {
    display: flex;
}

.Navbar-dropdown {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.Navbar-dropdownMenu {
    display: none;
}

.Navbar-dropdown:hover .Navbar-dropdownMenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
        <nav class="Navbar">
            <a class="Navbar-brand Navbar-link" href="./">Brand</a>
            <div class="Navbar-menu">
                <a class="Navbar-link Text-uppercase" href="./">Link 1</a>
                <a class="Navbar-link Text-uppercase" href="./">Link 2</a>


                <div class="Navbar-dropdown">
                    <button class="Navbar-dropdownBtn">Kieli</button>
                    <div class="Navbar-dropdownMenu">
                        <a class="Navbar-link" href="../en-fi/">Suomi</a>
                        <a class="Navbar-link" href="../en-gb/">Englanti</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Why are you using flex on the dropdown menu instead of absolute positioning?

Comment: @VeeK Should I be?

Comment: You should. Think about how the dropdown is displayed. Its either over the button that triggers it or under it. In any case, its displayed **over** other elements so absolute positioning is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content is pushed because your dropdown menu is in your `Navbar-dropdown`. On hover you're displaying the dropdown content and as it takes vertical space it pushes the content.

To avoid that, you have to set the dropdown content position to `absolute`.
Don't forget to set the position of the `Navbar-dropdown` to relative.

```css
.Navbar {
    display: flex;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: lightgray;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.Navbar-menu {
    display: flex;
}

.Navbar-dropdown {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.Navbar-dropdownMenu {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
}

.Navbar-dropdown:hover .Navbar-dropdownMenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<nav class="Navbar">
    <a class="Navbar-brand Navbar-link" href="./">Brand</a>
    <div class="Navbar-menu">
        <a class="Navbar-link Text-uppercase" href="./">Link 1</a>
        <a class="Navbar-link Text-uppercase" href="./">Link 2</a>


        <div class="Navbar-dropdown">
            <button class="Navbar-dropdownBtn">Kieli</button>
            <div class="Navbar-dropdownMenu">
                <a class="Navbar-link" href="../en-fi/">Suomi</a>
                <a class="Navbar-link" href="../en-gb/">Englanti</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```